# Feeds XPath Parser - Update existing content

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds

I have created a Feed Importer and used XPath Parser for mapping. I have problem with updating a existing content. For example I have this xml structure.

```
<node>
  <nid>1</nid>
  <title>Title 1</title>
</node>
<node>
  <nid>2</nid>
  <title>Title 2</title>
</node>
```

I started importer and everything is OK. I set NID as unique and check "Update existing content" in Node Process settings. So when I run importer again whit the same data this nodes have updated again.

Why have been updated ? The source is the same and don't any difference. Should It display, there is no new content to add if I start importer again and again with the same data ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't recognized the nid field as unique,

What is  the field associated with the nid value?

If you have a custom field associated with the nid :

You should install https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation

and add the validation of the field at 
http://yourwebsite/admin/structure/field_validation

and set the validator with the value "Unique values".

Sometimes a space in the value of the feed can cause this in this case you can use tamper for trim spaces :
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper

Comment: So this nid from srouce does not relation with Drupal. This is id from another system and I just use it for GUID and set as unique. I will try with feeds tamper first trim the value and second set unique for it.

Comment: No it does not work. Create tamper for GUID (set trim and unique tamper). But every time when I run import the nodes are updating. Some times does not update. So if I run 5 times 4 of them will be updated 1 does not. This is so strange.

Comment: What kind of field is GUID?  text, number, others...?

Comment: GUID is a number. <event id="27731">...</event>. This is my real data and I get @id for GUID.

Comment: and what is it the type of field in your content type ( where do you store the id number)  is text, integer, Long text?

Comment: I don't have field in my content type for GUID. Should I ? I have saw that you understanding feeds. Can you tell me how I can import image in field_collection. So I have image tag in source with image link and I have field collection in my content type with image type. But I don't have this field collection field in mapping settings. Thank you men!

Comment: Your unique value should be associated with a field of the node created during the import, do you have associated it? 
(about the images in field collection you should  open a new question sorry)